# Why doesn't GHC complain when number constant out of range

Tags: haskell

GHC silently ignores out-of-range bits in numerical constants.

This behavior led me to wrestle with a rather strange bug today:

```
[0..256]::[Word8] -- evaluates to [0]!
```

I know *what caused* this bug (256 == 0 in a rot256 world)....  I am interested in why GHC/Haskell was designed not to complain about it at compile time.

(This behavior is true for Int also- for instance, `18446744073709551617::Int = 1`).

I've grown used to Haskell catching trivial compile time issues, and I was surprised when I had to track this down.

Comment: And by "rot256" I presume you mean "mod 256". ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect the honest answer is "because nobody implemented it yet". But I think there's another layer to that answer, which is that there are some subtle design issues.

For example: how should we know that `256` is out of range for `Word8`? Well, I suppose one answer might be that the compiler could notice that `Word8` is an instance of *all three* of `Integral`, `Ord`, and `Bounded`. So it could generate a check like

```
(256 :: Integer) > fromIntegral (maxBound :: Word8)
```

and evaluate this check at compile time. The problem is that all of a sudden we are running potentially *user-written* code (e.g. `maxBound`, `fromIntegral`, and `(>)` presumably all come from instance declarations that can be written by a programmer) at compile time. That can be a bit dangerous -- since it's impossible to tell if we'll ever get an answer! So at the very least you would want this check to be off by default, and presumably at least as hard to turn on as Template Haskell is.

On the other hand, it might also be possible to just build in a handful of instances that we "trust" -- e.g. `Word8` and `Int`, as you say. I would find that a bit disappointing, though perhaps such a patch would not be rejected.

Comment: I liked what the others said too, but I'm awarding the answer to you because this answer is closest to my current point of view about this proposed change, which is- It is possible, it would be good, .... it is hard to get right.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could GHC special-case this behavior to only work for literals or is that information not available to the compiler?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I'm pretty sure everything I said in this answer applies even if we're only interested in literals.

Comment: @DanielWagner Can you clarify?  How does checking numeric literals involve anything more complicated than a single comparison operation that is guaranteed to terminate?  Can you provide an example of where it might go wrong?  Note that I'm assuming that `maxBound` is statically known (i.e. the set of types you implement this for is static).

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez As mentioned in my answer: all of `fromIntegral`, `(>)`, and `maxBound` are user-written code, so each of those can diverge.

Comment: But that assumes that you implement the check in terms of `fromIntegral`, `(>)` and `maxBound`.  What if you simply bake in the check statically for a limited set of type using built-in functions provided by the compiler rather than the programmer?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez See my last paragraph.

Comment: We could instead agree that `fromIntegral` should throw on out-of-bounds values, but it's too late for that now.

Comment: Another possibility is to offer a compile flag that does something like `trace "numeric Overflow"` which prints a message to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation of the individual `Num` instance.  If you perform

```
> :type 1
1 :: Num a => a
```

So Haskell only initially converts something to a generic `Num`, and then you specify a type of `Word8`.  If you try

```
> (maxBound :: Word8) + 1
0
> maxBound :: Word8
255
```

This is what is known as an overflow, and holds true in many languages, notably C.  Haskell does not prevent you from doing this because there are legitimate cases where you might *want* to have overflow.  Instead, it is up to you, the programmer, to ensure that your input data is valid.  Also, as jozefg points out, it is impossible to know at compile time if every conversion is valid.

---

You could implement a `Cyclic` class that gives you the behavior you want, if you already have `Eq`, `Bounded`, and `Enum`:

```
class (Eq a, Bounded a, Enum a) => Cyclic a where
    next :: a -> a
    next a = if a == maxBound then minBound else succ a
    prev :: a -> a
    prev a = if a == minBound then maxBound else pred a

instance Cyclic Word8

> next 255 :: Word8
0
> prev 0 :: Word8
255
```

Luckily, for all `Integral` types, you already have `Enum` and `Eq`, and the only `Integral` I know of that doesn't have `Bounded` is `Integer`.  It's just a matter of adding `instance Cyclic <Int Type>` for each that you want to use.

Comment: I'm definitely familiar with overflow conditions....  I just don't expect to have to deal with it in Haskell.  If I wanted to use rot-numbers, I would expect to have a separate type for them, like Rot8, where `(255:Rot8) + (1::Rot8) = (0::Rot8)`, and it would even make sense to say `(256::Rot8)=(0:Rot8)`.

Comment: @jamshidh What about things like natural (unsigned) integers? They're a fairly common use case (indexing), but you rarely use them directly.  Instead, it's much more common to ensure that your index is within proper bounds before using, or use an indexing function that returns a `Maybe a` value instead.  It's essentially the same problem here.  You can actually make a `Cyclic` class that would work how you'd want, it'd depend on `Bounded` and `Enum`, but would be pretty trivial to implement.